# Insert NULL Values into nvarchar python mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I have a table with some nvarchar attributes. I am trying to insert values into that, sometimes some values are NULL. When I try to insert it in the db it inserts only the tuples without null values. Here is part of my code:

```
self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO product VALUES (N{0},N{1},N{2},{3})".format(item['name'],item['category'],item['original_price'],item['last_30_days_sales_volume']))
self.connection.commit()
```

Values are inserted in item by the following try..except:

```
try:
    item['last_30_days_sales_volume']= ("\'"+self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('...')+"\'")
except NoSuchElementException, e:
    item['last_30_days_sales_volume']= None
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Insert only tuples means what ? it insert tuples with some values in it and it ignore null values, can you give an example

Comment: If I try to insert an item like that: ('name','cat','$25', 300) it works fine and I can find the data in the db but if I try to insert ('name', None, '$2', 20) it doesn't insert it.

Comment: The Error is the following: Unknown column 'None' in 'field list', but if I try to insert 'NULL' instead  of None it inserts the string 'NULL'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After numerous attempts, I found the solution. Passing the None value didn't work but passing the value 'NULL' without the N in the beginning, which is needed for utf-8, saved in the Database all the tuples with the NULL values, and not the 'NULL' string. Therefore my query, in the end, was the following:

```
self.cursor.execute("INSERT IGNORE INTO product VALUES (N'{0}',{1},{2},{3})".format(item['name'],('N\''+item['category']+"\'" if item['category'] else 'NULL'),('N\''+item['original_price']+"\'" if item['original_price'] else 'NULL'),item['last_30_days_sales_volume'].encode('utf-8')))
```